# Running a service to get location details

Tags: android

In my app, i need to create an android service to periodically get mobile user's current location(latitude and longitude). The service should get user's location in every 5 minutes.. How can i do this in android service that would run in background. And is this the right approach?

Comment: @Reno: Maybe, it all depends on what he uses it for and the promises he makes to his users. Information is neither good or bad; just the use of that information can be.

Comment: what exactly is the problem. thats a long question...

Comment: In my app, i need to create an android service to periodically get mobile user's current location(latitude and longitude). The service should get user's location in every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a private/internal class(within your service) that implements locationListener and in the onStart meethod of your service you can requestLocationUpdates which will be listened by your listener

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDistance, listener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
      LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
      mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
}
 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
    {


        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
        {
            Log.i("**************************************", "Location changed");

            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude(); 
            String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitude = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitude = " + loc.getLongitude();             
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), Text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a service to accomplish this. In order to get location every 5mins, in your app, on the activity you can implement the location listener. While setting up the location manager, you can specify the `minTime = 5mins (300000 ms)`. The `onlocationChanged` method will be called every 5 mins or when the distance `change > minDistance`, which ever occurs first.

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener listener = new MyLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 300000, minDistance, listener);
```