# What is the best solution for collecting location info in the background?

Tags: android

I want to make an application that gets the phone location each 30 min and save it to a DB (and transmits to a webserver).

The application should be running in the background for a few hours while the user can be doing other things with his phone (games, calls...)

Can someone please advice what is the best solution for this project? (Service? AlermManager?)

Comment: Jepp, service is the right way to go, [you will find this thread interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909805/determining-if-gps-is-failing-to-get-a-lock)

Answer (score 2):

In my case [**Android - Service**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) is the best solution for me.

For service Example - [ServicesDemo - Using Android Services](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html)

[Define and consume your own service](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) .

**EDIT:** look at this SO question [Running a service to get location details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179651/running-a-service-to-get-location-details)

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Will take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

A good way to this is by [registering a pending Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) instead of an location listener.

This makes it possible that your App is not running while it is waiting for a new location. The pending Intent should point to an [intent service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), in that way you don't need to think about working in the background after you received a new location.

If you don't need more location updates you only have to [unregister the intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).